# Как использовать CMake с несколькими пакетными менеджерами?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, vcpkg

В C++ проектах я использую менеджер пакетов [Conan](https://conan.io). До недавнего времени я использовал [специальный враппер](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan) для CMake, который позволяет указать необходимые зависимости и их опции непосредственно из CMakeLists-файла. Как данный, так и стандартный способ (через conanfile.txt/conanfile.py), требуют внесения изменений в CMakeLists - включения `conanbuildinfo.cmake`.

Теперь у меня возникла необходимость поддержки [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) (и, потенциально, любого другого менеджера пакетов). Собственно, вопрос: можно ли как-то вынести установку зависимостей из процесса генерации билдскриптов CMake'ом? Возможно, кто-то уже с этим сталкивался и может поделиться какими-то best practices?

Comment: `vcpkg.json`, прочтите https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications/manifests/

Comment: @Kotomi, спасибо, посмотрю.